# How to use Render

Tags: ajax, richfaces

I am new to richfaces, ajax and analyzing code that contains:
render="#{render}"

Any one can explain what render do in general and in this code in particular.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<body>
 <ui:composition>
  <div style="display: table;">
   <div style="display: table-row">
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 5px;">
     <ui:include src="/view/main/common/scans_selector.xhtml">
      <ui:Param name="prefix" value="individual_scan" />
      <ui:Param name="year" value="#{individualScanDetailsController.scans.year}" />
      <ui:Param name="month" value="#{individualScanDetailsController.scans.month}" />
      <ui:Param name="type" value="#{individualScanDetailsController.scans.type}" />
                        <ui:Param name="show_type" value="true" />
     </ui:include>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell">
     <h:commandButton id="individual_scan_selector_submit"
      value="#{msg['LoadScans']}">
      <f:ajax listener="#{individualScanDetailsController.processIndividualScanScansSelectorEvent()}"
       execute="individual_scan_scans_year individual_scan_scans_month individual_scan_scans_type"
       render="#{render}" />
     </h:commandButton>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `#{render}` can be part of included _scans_selector.xhtml_

Answer (score 0):

The render attribute provides a reference to one or more components on the page that need updating after an Ajax interaction.

You need to find in your project, the value of "render" (JSF Expression Language)

You may want to refer to these or google on your own - 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12404888/1193815
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_ajax.htm
https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Common_Ajax_attributes.html#sect-Component_Reference-Common_Ajax_attributes-Rendering